# Nginx deny 503 for URL unless url parameter is present

Tags: nginx

I am currently restricting a WordPress file wp-login.php to only my IP address - but I would like to allow access to that page if a given URL parameter is present.

So essentially this is what I have tried

```
location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
    if ($arg_action = "true") {
        break;
    }

    allow xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    deny all;
    // fastcgi_params
}
```

So in this code snippet, if a user visits wp-login.php?action=true, the page should show. But if a user visits wp-login.php they should get denied.

This code however is not working, any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Wordpress forwards between different scripts, and does posts to those scripts. I suspect if you work out how to do this you'll lock yourself out. Locking to your IP seems more than sufficient. Just keep Wordpress up to date, keep backups, and you should be fine.

Comment: I use a social login plugin that uses the wp-login page as the redirect uri that you have to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should would work for you, checks for `arg` if found it returns `error 418` which is then handed off to the named location `iplocation` this then checks the ips and does the rest of your configuration

```
error_page 418 = @iplocation;
recursive_error_pages on;
location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
    if ($arg_action = "true") {
        return 418;
    }
location @iplocation {  
    allow xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    deny all;
    // fastcgi_params
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **break** just exits if{}. It does not exit location.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#break

That code should work:

```
location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
    if ($arg_action != "true") {
        return 403;
    }

    allow xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    deny all;
    // fastcgi_params
}
```

Edit: fixed typo.